Conditional probability exercise: is this the right way?
I have a Pandas DataFrame and I have to calculate a particular probability.
I don't have problems with the code, but with the mathematical concepts I have to use.
The DataFrame contains information about the all towns in Italy (population, elevation, region, etc), and I have to calculate the probability that a randomly selected town with elevation over 2000 metres is from Lombardy (Italian region and this is exactly the text of the exercise).
The exercise is tagged as conditional probability exercise, and I am trying to solving it using it, but I am not sure if my way of thinking is correct.
I made this considerations:

Event A: towns over 2000 metres
Event B: towns in Lombardy

so the probability that a random town over 2000 metres is from that region should be:
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
where:
$$
P(A\cap B) = \frac{\text{number of towns over 2000m and in Lombardy}}{\text{total number of towns in Italy}}
$$
and
$$
P(B) = \frac{\text{number of towns in Lombardy}}{\text{total number of towns in Italy}}
$$
if this is correct then the wanted probability should be:
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{\text{number of towns over 2000m and in Lombardy}}{\text{total number of towns in Italy}} \times \frac{\text{total number of towns in Italy}}{\text{number of towns in Lombardy}} = \frac{\text{number of towns over 2000m and in Lombardy}}{\text{number of towns in Lombardy}}
$$
which is the same results if I considered only the towns in the region, i.e. it doesn't seem to me a conditional probability problem.
I don't have the answer of the problem, but I would like to understand if the way of thinking is correct.
What do you think? Am I making a mistake?

"calculate the probability that a randomly selected town with elevation over 2000 metres is from Lombardy" - means (# towns over 2000 & lombardy)/(# towns over 2000)

thanks for the comments, that means I made a mistake in the text interpretation and in the definition of A and B events. Could you please explain the way of thinking? Thanks

your way of thinking is correct. conditional probability is exactly that - considering fractions of a subset (towns over 2000) of the whole population (towns in italy)

thanks, but my result is different to yours, so I made a mistake in the question interpretation. The right one should be: "what is the probability a town is from Lombardy given it's over 2000m?" instead I answered the question: "what is the probability a town is over 2000m given it's in Lombardy?", which they are 2 different things.
